# thread hungs,high cpu, c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll

i have code like this:

```
bool isActive = false;

DWORD WINAPI 123Thread(LPVOID);

DWORD WINAPI 123Thread(LPVOID)
{
    while (1) 
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
        {
            MessageBox(0,L"1234456",L"6544321", MB_OK);
        }
    return 1;
    }
}

DWORD APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, 123Thread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

everything works ok,but CPU initilization is very high,and app crashes after 5-10 min work.in Proccess Explorer my dll state everytime is "Running" with extremly number of cycles,but others similiar dll show state like "Wait:WrUserRequest".how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 123 tread is looping infinitely keeping the cpu busy all the time. Put a sleep after GetAsyncKeyState call:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x));
```

While sleeping, your process won't consume CPU resources. There might be some overhead since the kernel has to juggle processes around, but that is very insignificant.